# How to move /boot and / to different disk

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Debian server with multiple HDDs.
`/`, `/home/`, `swap` and others are LVM Logical Volumes.
`/boot` is on a small partition at the beginning of one of the physical HDDs.
`fstab` uses UUID for `/boot` and `/dev/mapper/` for the rest.

I want to move the root `/` and `/boot` partition to my new SSD.

My idea is to create the same small partition on the SSD and use dd to copy it over.
Then I will mount the new boot partition (live distro probably necessary) and run grub-install?
Also, update UUID of the new /boot.

The rest of the SSD will be LVM partition.
If I add it to the same VG I can migrate it by forcing PV to the LV AFAIK.

Will it work?
Is there a better way?

Edit:
I am using BIOS boot.

Comment: What's your boot mechanism? BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: I am using BIOS boot